# How to get output from one observer file to another observer file?

Tags: magento-1.7

I have two observer file. One event is called for salesrule_validator_process and other observer file is called for sales_quote_collect_totals_after. How to get the result of salesrule_validator_process in sales_quote_collect_totals_after.

Comment: Both method are in same class?

Comment: 1.Test_Subtotal_Model_Observer -  sales_quote_collect_totals_after  
2.Test_Mrp_Model_Observer - salesrule_validator_process. Not same class.

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala   If it has same class then what will be the solution? Give me any solution .

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the observers are in the same class, you can save the result in a property, because by default observers are instantiated as singleton. That means, the same object is used in both events:

```
class Stack_Example_Model_Observer
{
    protected $_result;

    public function validatorProcess($observer)
    {
        $this->_result = ...;
    }

    public function afterTotalsCollect($observer)
    {
        // here you can use $this->_result;
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you can always use a third class as singleton. Simple example:

```
class Stack_Example_Model_Result extends Varien_Object
{

}
```

Usage:

```
// first observer:
Mage::getSingleton('stack_example/result')->setData('result', $result);

// second observer:
$result = Mage::getSingleton('stack_example/result')->getData('result');
```

This example result singleton is just a dumb data object, but you could add more meaningful methods or actually process the result there instead of in the observer classes.

Comment: stack_example/result - Here what 'result' stand for? I am getting fatal error Fatal error: Call to a member function getData() on boolean

Comment: "result"  stands for the class name part after Model_ - please look up the basics for custom module creation and working with models.

Comment: I created module file Result.php still it gives me fatal error.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**  If values in different class

You can use magento registry for that

for storing registry you can do as below

```
Mage::register('my_need', $myvalue);
```

and getting value

```
Mage::registry('my_need');
```

after that unregister registry like below

```
Mage::unregister('my_need');
```

**Solution 2:**  if it is in the same class

```
class1{
protected $_myvariable;
function 1(){
   //set value
  $this->_myvariable  = $myvalue;
}
function 2(){
//fetch Value 
  print_r($this->_myvariable); 

} 
}
```